# How to remap keys only for a particular keyboard in Linux?

Tags: xinput, xbindkeys, xte

I have a numpad connected via USB and my goal is to be able to remap keys on that numpad so they can run custom commands or be mapped to other key combinations.

I have this in my `.xbindkeysrc` file:

```
~ $ cat .xbindkeysrc
"xte 'keydown Super_L' 'key Left' 'keyup Super_L'"
  m:0x10 + c:79 + Release
  Mod2 + KP_Home
```

This remaps the NUM 7 key (which normally prints 7) to `Super_L + Left Arrow`. That's great and it works, BUT FOR ALL KEYBOARDS, while my goal is to make it work only for the numpad.

Been searching how to do it, but the closest I got was to use `xinput set-button-map`. Unfortunately, this seems to only work for devices like mouses. I like tried fetching what the button map is for the numpad with `xinput get-button-map [device id]` but it just prints numbers from 1 to 7 and I definitely have more buttons on my keypad, so it doesn't necessarily make sense.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

Consider using https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd. It was written for this purpose and works across the entire system.

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Find the deviceID first, using `xinput list`

```
$ xinput list

⎣ Virtual core keyboard
...
↳   USB Keyboard     id=19  [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**key mapping per device/keyboard**

*(This will only map keys. See below for mapping scripts to keys)*

`setxkbmap` has the option to target a specific device (keyboard).

Then query the `setxkbmap` config to see your device settings (I will use '19'):

```
$ setxkbmap -device 19 -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(euro)+us(intl):2+inet(evdev)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

The `symbols` is what we're looking for; these can be found in `ls /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`. The arguments refer to a subsection in the file, for example `xkb_symbols "intl" {`

> To add any of the *available* options like for example, rupeesign, you
>   could do `setxkbmap -device 19 -option rupeesign:4`
>
> *to reset the options, use `setxkbmap -device 19 -option` without further arguments.*

However, you want some custom configuration, and that is a bit more tricky, because simply adding a custom file in that folder and using it does not work.

So create some folders and create a tempfile with the current config.

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/xkb/symbols
cd ~/.config/xkb 
setxkbmap -device 19 -print > tempfile.txt
touch symbols/mysymbol
```

Edit `tempfile.txt` so it contains `mysymbol(mymapping)`

```
...
xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us(euro)+us(intl):2+inet(evdev)+mysymbol(mymapping)"
```

Edit `symbol/mysymbol` any way you want, see `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` for examples.
This one adds a Bitcoin symbol to `num 7` key .

```
partial
xkb_symbols "mymapping" {
    key <AE07> { [  7,   &,   U20BF ]  };

};
```

Now, finally, to activate this mapping, use `xkbcomp` ( note `-i 19` to set the device)

```
xkbcomp -i 19 -I$HOME/.config/xkb tempfile.txt $DISPLAY
```

(This will probably show some `warning` messages, but it still works)

**Mapping keys to start a script**

There is a tool for mapping key to a script: `actkbd`

install:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/thkala/actkbd 
$ cd actkb
$ make 
$ sudo make install
```

Then find the devicename for your keyboard in `/dev/input/`,
in my case it is `/dev/input/by-id/usb-_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd`

You should now have a config file `/etc/actkbd.conf` containing some examples, can all be all be removed. Here are some more practical examples

```
# 'a' starts gedit
30:::gedit
# 'shift+7' starts a custom script. (keynumber 8 for some reason)
42+8:::/home/me/myscript.py
```

To find the keynumber (or keycombination), use the 's' option:

```
$ actkbd -d /dev/input/by-id/usb-_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd -s
```

After your configuration in /etc/actkbd.conf, start the program  (use `-D` for background mode )

```
$ actkbd -d /dev/input/by-id/usb-_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd
```

Comment: No need for creating all those dirs - `xkbcomp` works in both directions; simply `xkbcomp -i 19 $DISPLAY foo.xkb`, edit `foo.xkb`, `xkbcomp -i 19 foo.xkb $DISPLAY` should do. It even works in a single shot `xkbcomp -i dev $DISPLAY - | some_filter | xkbcomp -i dev - $DISPLAY`, though the xkb format is too "structured" for awk or sed.

Comment: @mosvy you're right, that returns the full layout (~2000lines), but might not be as easy to edit for anyone new to the format.

Comment: I tried following your instructions, this is the error I'm getting when trying to run: `xkbcomp -i...`

`Can't find file "evdev" for keycodes include   Exiting Abandoning keycodes file "(null)"`

Comment: I also get this error even if I don't change tempfile.txt and am trying to load it as is.